# could any one tell me why $g$ is not bounded on $S$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},g(z)=e^{i z}$, $S=\{z:Re(z)\in [-\pi,\pi]\}$, could any one tell me why $g$ is not bounded on $S$?

$g(z)=e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$ so I guess when real part is bounded on $S$, so $g$ should be bounded on $S$, what about just $e^z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, let $z$ be pure imaginary and large in magnitude.  For $g(z)$ to be bounded, both the real and imaginary parts need to be bounded.  $\cos z$ is not bounded when $z$ is not real.

Comment: Ross, why wouldn't $\cos z$ not be bounded when $z$ is not real?

Comment: @Q.matin:  because $\cos z = \frac 12(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$  If $z=10i$ you get (a little more than) $\frac 12 e^{10}\approx 11013$.  As you follow the imaginary axis, it goes off to infinity in both directions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!